# Quickfix is slow

Tags: quickfix

```
    long time=System.currentTimeMillis();
    MarketDataRequest request=new MarketDataRequest();
    System.out.println("First: " +(System.currentTimeMillis()-time));


    time=System.currentTimeMillis();
    request=new MarketDataRequest();
    System.out.println("Second: "+ (System.currentTimeMillis()-time));
```

Result:

First: 43
Second: 0

43ms seems very slow...any reason why the first creation of the object takes sooo long?

Comment: What happens when you create a new MarketDataRequest **request1** rather than assigning to the old **request** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possible causes are Java class loading and JIT compiler overhead.

Comment: How can I load the classes/compile in advance?

Comment: The easiest way is to do something similar to your example. Create an instance of the message at startup time so the classes will be loaded when you want to send a similar message later.